# How can I append to a shared file from multiple processes in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Please read the question carefully before marking it as duplicate.

- We have a Windows file server.
- We also have multiple *.NET* processes running on different machines all of which periodically append to a shared file (on the file server) (let's call it `foo.txt`)

How can we ensure serialized writes to the file from all the processes without having to create a *.lock* file on the file server.

Note using a `lock`/`Mutex`/`Semaphore`/`WaitHandle` is not an option as the processes are running on different machines.

The best I could come up with (which I had no reason to believe it wouldn't work) is:

```
private void TryWrite(string filePath, string payload)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(payload);
            }
            return;
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * (i + 1));
        }
    }

    // log unable to write
}
```

But I am still getting occasional interleaved writes from different processes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Rather than sharing a single file that can be written to by multiple processes in multiple locations, I would consider centralising the writing of the file and perhaps implementing an API that each process calls to do that.  In that way, you can guarantee that the writes take place in the precise order they are received, and without these extenuating issues. Not a _direct_ answer I know, but it would solve your issue.

Comment: Yep that would be the proper way of doing it. But we are dealing with a legacy enterprise architecture here.

Comment: Could you define some moments when different machines write to the file... some kind of rules to avoid overlapping

Comment: @Johnny unfortunately not. The writers can write at any time but we don't care if they miss occasionally or have to wait for some time. (as they do in the current solution)

Comment: why not use client server model, and every time you want to write into the file you send the message to a server and he process the queue, this would avoid any problem you may have between process as the server will take care of the sync process

Comment: Maybe then try to use `FileStream.Open(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare)` method and catch `IOException`...

Comment: @Johnny That's what I am doing!

Comment: Why do you use FileShare.Read? I would prefer FileShare.None...

Comment: I want the file to still be readable. It's the writes I am trying to serialize.

Comment: Your code should work and the design is good. How did you determine that it is not working?

Comment: @usr I expected it to work as well but I am still getting multiple processes interleaving their writes on the same line. So occasionally I get lines containing values from multiple processes.

Comment: Maybe multiple TryWrite calls per line?

Comment: It can't be, only a single line is permitted in that method. And all writers use the same method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is OK. It will be something like multiple calls, people not using this method, other programs, you not correctly reading the file, etc.. I don't know what it is but these kinds of things are the solution. I'd be interested in the cause when you find it.